# Can the ordering of the rationals be defined from their field structure alone?

Tags: model-theory

Consider the structure $(\mathbb{Q},+,*,-,0,1)$. Can the canonical ordering of the rational field be defined by a formula from their field structure alone? If yes, can someone give me a formula that defines it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\exists z_1 \exists z_2 \exists z_3 \exists z_4 (y-x=z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2+z_4^2)$$

Comment: To explain for the OP: clearly this formula implies $y\ge x$ since the sum of squares must be positive. The converse direction is basically [the four square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem), just rephrased over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: If memory serves this is in fact optimal in the sense that there is no formula of the form $$\varphi(x,y)\equiv \exists z_1\exists z_2\exists z_3(\psi(x,y,z_1,z_2,z_3))$$ with $\psi$ quantifier-free. But I can't find a citation at the moment.